# Passing by reference to comparator function (C++11)

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, optimization, pass-by-reference

I am trying to speed up my code (minimal, reproducible example below) and I was told that passing by reference would be a more efficient method for my comparator function. That was the first time I heard of the phrase, so I looked it up and found some websites with examples, but I don't understand when and how to use it. How would I use it in this case?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class arrMember {
public:
    int var;
    arrMember(int var) :
        var(var) {}
    arrMember() {};
};

array<int, 1000000> arraySource;

array<arrMember, 1000000> arrayObjects;

bool compare(arrMember(x), arrMember(y)) {
    return (x.var < y.var);
}

void arrayPrint() {
    ofstream output("arrayPrint.txt");
    for (int k = 0; k != arrayObjects.size(); k++) {
        output << arrayObjects[k].var << endl;
    }

    output.close();
}

void sort() {
    int j = 0;
    for (auto i = arraySource.begin(); i != arraySource.end(); i++, j++) {
        arrayObjects[j] = arrMember(arraySource[j]);
    }

    sort(arrayObjects.begin(), arrayObjects.end(), compare);
}

int main(){
    random_device rd{};
    mt19937 engine{ rd() };
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{ 0, 9999 };
    for (int x = 0; x < arraySource.size(); ++x){
        arraySource[x] = dist(engine);
    }

    cout << "Executing sort...\n";
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    sort();
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    double timeDiff = ((double)(t2 - t1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "Sort finished. CPU time was " << timeDiff << " seconds.\n";

    arrayPrint();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For trivially small types, passing by reference doesn't help; copy-constructing a class consisting of a single `int` is basically the same cost as taking the address of an existing instance, and copy constructing means the comparator doesn't need to dereference a pointer to find the value, it's already on the local stack.

For a larger type with expensive copy-construction, you could change (original code minus unnecessary parens):

```
bool compare(arrMember x, arrMember y) {
    return x.var < y.var;
}
```

to:

```
bool compare(const arrMember& x, const arrMember& y) {
    return x.var < y.var;
}
```

and harvest a meaningful speed-up, but for a simple `int` wrapper class, you gain nothing.

What *will* make a difference, regardless of the size of the `class` in question, is replacing raw functions with functors (or lambdas, which are syntactic sugar for functors). `std::sort` specializes the template to the *type* of the comparator, and functions themselves aren't types; they're effectively instances of the set of functions that share the same prototype. So if you implement both:

```
bool compare(const arrMember& x, const arrMember& y) {
    return x.var < y.var;
}
bool compareReverse(const arrMember& x, const arrMember& y) {
    return x.var > y.var;
}
```

and call `std::sort` with both `compare` and `compareReverse` at different points in your program, it only makes one specialization of `std::sort` for `bool (*)(const arrMember&, const arrMember&)`, and that single specialization must actually pass around and call the provided function through a pointer; the cost of calling a function at all is significantly higher than the trivial cost of performing the comparison itself, and calling through a pointer is usually even more expensive.

By contrast, functors (and lambdas) are unique types, so `std::sort` can fully specialize to them, including inlining the comparison, so no call to the comparator function ever occurs; the comparator logic is inlined directly into a unique specialization of `std::sort`. So instead of:

```
bool compare(const arrMember& x, const arrMember& y) {
    return x.var < y.var;
}
std::sort(..., compare);
```

you could do this:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator()(const arrMember& x, const arrMember& y) const {
        return x.var < y.var;
    }
};
std::sort(..., compare());
```

or inline the whole thing as a C++11 lambda:

```
std::sort(..., [](const arrMember& x, const arrMember& y) { return x.var < y.var; });
```

Either way, the code will run faster; [Godbolt shows](https://godbolt.org/z/E3BJkJ) that either function pointer approach is pretty much the same, while with the functor approach, you reduce runtime relative to the function pointer approach by about a third (saving a little more passing by value in this case, but hardly worth the trouble to think about most of the time; I'd default to passing by `const` reference, and only consider switching if profiling said it was slow, and the type was simple enough that passing by value might help).

This benefit to templates and functors is why C++'s `std::sort` reliably beats C's `qsort` when used appropriately; C lacks templates, so it can't specialize `qsort` at all, and must always call the comparator through a function pointer. If you use `std::sort` with a function, it's no real improvement on `qsort`, but used with a functor/lambda, it generates *much* faster code at the expense of generating *more* code (a unique specialization of `std::sort` for each functor/lambda). You could get the same benefit in C by copy-pasting the code implementing `qsort`, getting rid of the comparator and inlining the comparison yourself, but that's a *lot* of maintenance overhead; C++ templates do 99% of the work for you, you just need to remember to use functors/lambdas for your callbacks, not raw functions.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll try using a lambda function later. Thanks for the response. If I could, I would upvote your answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Nothing prevents the compiler from generating a specialized (partially evaluated) version of your function for a set of arguments known at compile time. No compiler seems to do this (at least for C++, but ghc (Haskell) does), but the same should be achieved by inlining. `std::sort` can be inlined, then the call to the predicate can be inlined as well. However, std::sort seems to be complex enough to not get inlined.It totally changes if you e.g. use std::find_if. Here, a call with a functions gets inlined but not the functor: https://godbolt.org/z/xhMxHq

Answer (score 1):

In your code you define the comparator function as

```
bool compare(arrMember(x), arrMember(y)) {
    return (x.var < y.var);
}
```

The function has two parameters of type `arrMember` passed by value. This means `x` and `y` are copies of the arguments passed to the function. So when you sort your array, each time the comparator is called (which O(n * logn) times) two temporary objects are created, compared and then destroyed. You can modify your function to take the parameters by reference:

```
bool compare(arrMember const& x, arrMember const& y) {
    return x.var < y.var;
}
```

This way, the function does not use a copy a reference to the original value. It's a const reference that cannot be modified.

The idea now is that this saves the temporary objects as copies and thus saves runtime. However, the best advice is to measure instead of argue. I've modified your code a little bit to run both versions.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

constexpr size_t N=1000000;

class arrMember {
public:
    int var;
    arrMember(int var) :
        var(var) {}
    arrMember() {};
};

bool compare_by_value(arrMember x, arrMember y) {
    return (x.var < y.var);
}

bool compare_by_reference(arrMember const& x, arrMember const& y) {
    return (x.var < y.var);
}


template<typename C>
void sort(array<arrMember, N>& a, C comp) {
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), comp);
}

int main(){
    random_device rd{};
    mt19937 engine{ rd() };
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{ 0, 9999 };

    array<arrMember, N> a;
    std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), [&]() {return arrMember{dist(engine)};});

    int tmp=0;
    cout << "Executing sort...\n";
    {
        array<arrMember, N> x = a;
        clock_t t1 = clock();
        sort(x, compare_by_value);
        clock_t t2 = clock();
        double timeDiff = ((double)(t2 - t1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "Sort finished. CPU time was " << timeDiff << " seconds.\n";
        tmp += x.front().var;
    }

    {
        array<arrMember, N> x = a;
        clock_t t1 = clock();
        sort(x, compare_by_reference);
        clock_t t2 = clock();
        double timeDiff = ((double)(t2 - t1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "Sort finished. CPU time was " << timeDiff << " seconds.\n";
        tmp += x.front().var;
    }



    return tmp;
}
```

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3hlrD044UqzA3Z96) is an example of the output:

> Start
>
> Executing sort... 
>   Sort finished. CPU time was 0.105382 seconds. 
>   Sort finished. CPU time was 0.108179 seconds.
>
> 0
>
> Finish

It seems that there is no difference between both version, so what happened? An optimizing compiler will inline the comparator into the sort algorithm code. To do this, the call in the sort routing is replaced with the body of the function and since the function does not modify the arguments, no copies have to be created to prevent modification of the "passed" values.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it makes a lot of sense. But now I'm back to the drawing board for how to sort faster...

Comment: @jared `std::sort` is O(n logn) which is the optimal complexity for general sorting algorithms. Depending on your input data you could find something faster, e.g. when the data is mostly sorted another sorting algorithm may perform better, but not in the worst-case. If you want to sort integers Bucketsort could be an option.

Comment: @jared: Also note: Your original benchmark (but not Jens's) includes the cost of copying from the source array to the temporary array (and it's only done once, on fresh memory, which on Linux-like systems may be being lazily copy-on-write mapped to the zero page, increasing the cost of initializing it). So some of your measured cost isn't the sort, it's the cost of allocating and initializing 4 MB of memory. So make sure to limit the benchmark to the sort itself. After that, yes, a count sort would perform better in this case (at the relatively minor cost of a 10000 element array of counts).

Comment: Side-note: Are you sure the compiler inlined the comparison? Using a function instead of a functor (or lambda, which is just syntactic sugar for a functor) is supposed to inhibit that optimization (because `sort`'s template can only specialize to the function prototype, not the specific function). Seems just as likely that passing by reference didn't matter because the class in question was effectively a POD type where it cost just as little to copy as it would to take a reference to it.

Comment: On testing, with proper functors for inlining, [functors are consistently faster, but functors receiving by reference are actually slower than functors receiving by value](https://godbolt.org/z/E3BJkJ) (which makes sense, given how cheap copying the object in question is).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, my code measures the copying of the array, but for this assignment my Prof will be measuring everything I do, including copying to a new array if I do that. (For the actual assignment I'm given a linked list to sort, not an array.)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Also, I can't use a count sort for the actual data since there are 1000000 members that need to be sorted and they are all unique. I have tried radix sort, but it seems to provide no advantage. I believe that my radix sort is not much faster than the built in `std::sort()` because I have too many loops, but I can't seem to think of how to reduce them...

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm not sure if it matters if you use a functor or a function pointer. The passed function is very small and static, so the compiler should be able to inline that independent on it being a function or functor. I compiled the code with godbolt and the compiler creates two instances of `std::std::__introsort_loop`.

Comment: @Jens: It matters. The compiler makes two instances of `std::__introsort_loop` because the prototypes of each function differed, but it only specializes to the prototype, not the specific function; if you look at the contents of the function-based `__introsort_loop`, it includes `call REGISTER` multiple times (as do its associated `__heap_select` and `__adjust_heap` functions), each time followed by `test al, al` (to see if the return was true or false). The functor-based `__introsort_loop` contains *no* calls through a register; the comparisons are inlined.

Comment: It's not the compiler's fault here. Templates have strict rules, and the rules for `std::sort` only allow it to specialize on the *type* of the comparator. A function's type is base on the prototype, not the specific function. A functor (or lambda) is a unique type in itself, and thus can fully specialize. Using functions makes inlining impossible, but does make it possible to use the same specialization of `std::sort` with different functions sharing the prototype (e.g. forward and reverse sorts), which reduces binary size by removing the 90% of code that is duplicated in each specialization.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't think that the compiler must not create a specialization for a certain set of parameters, in our case a specific comparator function. The observable behavioor of the program does not change, so this would be a valid optimization. Compilers don't do this, but it would be possible and even not too hard to implement for compile-time arguments. Why not partially evaluate a function with all compile-time arguments and replace that single function call with this evaluation? It's a trade-off decision between size and speed, but both decisions are valid.